# Jquery Sortable for child not working in IE

Tags: jquery-ui

Guys i have the following  UL elements. The nested UL(nestsort) items are sortable in the **IE browser Version 7** , but the drag movement seems wired ,while it works smooth in firefox.Please click on this link http://jsfiddle.net/Ds7ds/1/ from IE , the code is in jsfiddle.

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li>
        <p> item 1</p>
        <ul id="nestsort">
            <li>
                Sub item 1 
            </li>
            <li>
                Sub item 2
            </li>
            <li>
                Sub item 3 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p> item 2</p>
    </li>
</ul>



$("#sortable").sortable();
$("#nestsort").sortable();
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you :

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({

cancel: "#nestsort"

});

$("#nestsort").sortable();
```

Wish you luck.